# Trying to connect to LDAPS (Windows active directory) but keep receiving Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) error

Tags: ldap, openssl

I've been given a certificate by the person who runs our Active Directory server so I can use LDAPS but I can't get it to work. When verifying with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:636 -CAfile  ~/filename.pem
```

I just get `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)` every time.

I'm wondering if the server is misconfigured because I have tried to get the certificate straight from the server like this (from Ubuntu 16.04 client):

```
openssl s_client -host domain.com -port 636 -prexit -showcerts
```

And I get the same error message even with that.

Whereas if I type:

```
openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443 -prexit -showcerts
```

I get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

I've tried copying certificates into `/etc/ssl/certs`. I've tried using `-CApath` and `-CAfile` to give various certificates to the server.

Really I'm asking if the error code 20 in response to an openssl with `-showcerts` means that the server really is misconfigured or if I'm just not doing it right, because I'd hate to spend more time on the client when it's the server that's misbehaving.

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in filename.pem
```

returns (with some redactions):

Certificate:

```
Data:

    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: CN=My organisation RootCA
    Validity
        Not Before: May 20 13:11:34 2016 GMT
        Not After : May 20 13:21:34 2021 GMT
    Subject: DC=org, DC=example, CN=My organisation Issuing CA
```

And then a load of stuff that all looks fine. That is the root certificate, is it not? It says RootCA on it, after all.

Oh yes, and if I feed that certificate in, with

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:636 -CAfile  file.pem
```

I do get a different error message:

> Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)

So this feels like I have one certificate but not the other.

I did get another one using `nmap --script ssl-cert` but I don't seem to be able to get anything other than error code 20 with that.

Comment: If you have a Windows machine handy, you can use ldp.exe (download from Microsoft.com) to verify the LDAPS configuration, That said, assuming you're connecting to an AD Domain Controller, the only "configuration" is to have a Computer Certificate. There's literally nothing for us to do beyond that to enable LDAPS

Comment: Add the output of `openssl x509 -noout -text -in filename.pem` to your question.

Comment: If `telnet domain.com 636` is working, use the `nmap ssl-cert -vv` script. to dump the domain controller certificate. That should provide more information than the brain-damaged openssl client. You should also do a `nslookup domain.com` and test *every* IP address listed because you may be getting an invalid IP.

Comment: **No, that's not a root cert.** It is _issued_ by the root CA, but its _subject_ (owner) is 'issuing CA' which presumably is an intermediate (and certainly is not the root). OpenSSL by default will not treat a non-root as an anchor. Either get the actual root cert, or in OpenSSL 1.0.2 up commandline use `-partial_chain` to validate using a non-root anchor.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't mention I actually have got the whole thing verified using partial_chain. However, that doesn't help me for the actual application, which is using LDAPS to secure an LDAP connection within Shiny Server http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#ldap-and-active-directory. Or does it?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you've received a file containing single root CA cert to validate the TLS server cert. Make sure it's ASCII-armored base64-encoded (aka PEM).

Normally a certificate authority would not use the root CA's key to directly sign a TLS server public key. For security reasons one uses an intermediate CA, also often called issuing CA, for that.

Now the TLS client has to verify the whole CA cert chain and it needs access to intermediate CA cert and root CA cert.

In case of a well-configured TLS server you only need the root CA cert in a local file because the server sends the intermediate CA cert during TLS connect. But some TLS servers are not well-configured.

You should see what's going on with

```
openssl s_client -connect ldap.example.com:636 -showcerts
```

like you already did.

If you do not have the root CA cert then ask the person who gave the intermediate CA cert to you.

Or if you have a Windows workstation in this AD domain it's somewhat likely that you find the root CA cert in the trust store of your Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

> That is the root certificate, is it not? It says RootCA on it, after all.

```
    Issuer: CN=My organisation RootCA
    Validity
        Not Before: May 20 13:11:34 2016 GMT
        Not After : May 20 13:21:34 2021 GMT
    Subject: DC=org, DC=example, CN=My organisation Issuing CA
```

No, this is not the root certificate, it is just signed by the root certificate. You need a certificate that looks like this:

```
    Issuer: CN=My organisation RootCA
    Subject: CN=My organisation RootCA
```

In other words, both Issuer and Subject must be your RootCA.

As it was probably created on the Windows machine, go to the certificate manager and export the root CA (just the certificate, you don't need the key).